# R global optimization problem with potential warnings/errors and the use of tryCatch

Tags: r, debugging, optimization, try-catch

Simply speaking, I have a function `f(x, t2)` and I want to find the value of `x` that maximize the integral of `f(x, t2)` with respect to `t2`. I choose pso algorithm to do the optimization. The excutable code is as follows

```
library(pso)
xl=0; xu=2000; n=1; t2l=100; t2u=2000; t1=1
g<-function(x, t2) t1*x/(t2+x)
h<-function(z) 1/z^n
gdot<-function(x, t2){
  c(x/(t2+x),-t1*x/(t2+x)^2)
}
logdetHinv<-function(dp, dw, t2){
  gmat=mapply(function(x) gdot(x,t2),dp)
  D0=gmat%*%diag(dw)%*%t(gmat)
  D1=gmat%*%diag(1/h(g(dp,t2)))%*%diag(dw)%*%t(gmat)
  2*log(det(D1))-log(det(D0))
}
obj<-function(x){
  dp=x[1:2]; dw=c(x[3],1-x[3])
  fitness_value=-integrate(Vectorize(function(t2) logdetHinv(dp, dw, t2)*1/(t2u-t2l)), t2l, t2u)$value
  return(ifelse(dw[2]>0, fitness_value, fitness_value+1e3))
}

x <- psoptim(rep(1,3), fn = obj, lower = c(rep(xl,2),0.1), upper = c(rep(xu,2), 0.9))$par
x
```

Because the global optimization involves some random procedure, it sometimes reports the correct result

```
> x
[1] 2000.0000  754.4146    0.5000
```

the other times it reports error

```
Error in integrate(Vectorize(function(t2) logdetHinv(dp, dw, t2) * 1/(t2u -  : 
  non-finite function value
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In log(det(D1)) : NaNs produced
2: In log(det(D0)) : NaNs produced
3: In log(det(D1)) : NaNs produced
4: In log(det(D0)) : NaNs produced
```

I suppose the algorithm tries take log of some negative values in `logdetHinv`, which returns `NaN` with a warning message, not an error yet, and finally causes error in `integrate`.

I want to avoid such values, maybe with `tryCatch`, like if there is warning in the function `logdetHinv`, it returns a very small value, but not `NaN`, so it will not cause error in `integrate`, and the `psoptim` is unlikely to choose such values when maximizing the objective function (minimizing `-integrate(logdetHinv)`) . I am not familiar with `tryCatch` in such complex situation. Where should I put the `tryCatch`? Thanks.

Moreover, I would like to know if there are some debugging techniques in R that allow me to know what random value (`D0/D1`) cause the error in this case. I guess it is some negative value in log, but it should not, as inside the log is a determinant of a positive definite matrix. In the traceback mode, in browse, if I type `D0` the object 'D0' will not be found.

Comment: `tryCatch({2*log(det(D1))-log(det(D0))}, warning = function(w) <your alternative return value>)`? This appears dangerous to me. I would try to find a better way to deal with negative determinants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would not use tryCatch which is usually more appropriate in testing than in your main code. Why don't you simply test the determinants in your function ? Something like that should work:

```
logdetHinv<-function(dp, dw, t2){
    gmat=mapply(function(x) gdot(x,t2),dp)
    D0=gmat%*%diag(dw)%*%t(gmat)
    D1=gmat%*%diag(1/h(g(dp,t2)))%*%diag(dw)%*%t(gmat)
    detD1 <- max(0.01, det(D1))
    detD0 <- max(0.01, det(D0)) 
    2*log(detD1)-log(detD0)
}
```

Comment: Good idea. The reason I think of `tryCatch` is that I am not sure it is due to negative determinant. Your code confirms me because it does not report error anymore. But it cannot be apply directly because the determinants is actually far smaller than 0.01, close to 0, which may be the source of the error. I modify it to
```detD1 <- max(0.01, 1e10*det(D1))
  detD0 <- max(0.01, 2e10*det(D0))```
works like a charm.

Comment: good to hear that you solved your problem.